# Problem with AJAX and WMD editor

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, browser-cache

Hi,

For the past 10 or 20 minutes I am experiencing problems with AJAX request and editor.

I am not able to post a comment.

And also my editor does not show the images for the formatting and the preview pane.

But in meta I don't encounter these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear your cache.

The JavaScript might be in need of freshening up if it's stalling for you.