# Should there be tags specifically for questions that get many dupes?

Tags: discussion, tags

I find that there are several questions that get asked many times, in many different forms. That all refer to the same underlying problem.

I suggest that we should consider making tags specifically for each of those problems.

---

For example, there are quite a few questions that ended up being a problem with the [browser cache](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-cache). That is, problems caused by having an old copy of the JavaScript files.

This problem appears in many forms:

- [Problem with AJAX and WMD editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/problem-with-ajax-and-wmd-editor)
- [Why can’t I comment on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25868/why-cant-i-comment-on-meta)
- [Did the AJAX just die on SuperUser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6126/did-the-ajax-just-die-on-superuser)

---

As a test, I created the tag [**`[browser-cache]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-cache), to help find questions that turn out to be caused by having an old cache.

Comment: Part of the reason for actually asking this question, was to tell users why the **`[browser-cache]`** tag exists.

Comment: Another possible candidate: http://meta.stackoveflow.com/tags/concurrency

Answer (score 3):

As long as the tags are useful and make sense, there is no harm in creating new tags. This is the entire reason we have this kind of tagging system to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

[What TheTXI said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/should-there-be-tags-specifically-for-questions-that-get-many-dupes/25879#25879). Tags are the most effective way to search [M]S[O|F|U], so use them liberally...

Answer (score 0):

Adding another tag:

[**`[merge-accounts]`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/merge-accounts)

For questions that ask for help combining multiple accounts *on the same site*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another tag:

[**`[rep-transfer]`**](http://meta.stackoveflow.com/tags/rep-transfer)

For questions that ask about transferring rep between two accounts.

Either on the same site, or across sites.

Includes:

- bounties
- bounties across domains
- moving rep from an account on one site, to the associated account on another.
- possibly even the effect of down-voting

Answer (score -1):

I think that's a great way to figure out what tags are needed.  Find a need and fill it.